# FirebaseRemoteConfig does not use options from FirebaseApp.initializeApp()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

On Android, if I initialize Firebase programmatically:

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setApplicationId(APP_ID)
        .setApiKey(apiKey)
        .setDatabaseUrl(databaseUrl)
        .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context.getApplicationContext(), options);
```

`FirebaseRemoteConfig` will not use the app ID that was used to initialize Firebase.

I need to initialize Firebase programmatically in my app because I have a switch to switch between the production & staging Firebase instances in my app, and relying on the `google-services.json` or specifying the values in `strings.xml` does not let me change those values at runtime.

Is there a way to specify the app ID to use with `FirebaseRemoteConfig` programmatically?

Comment: What version of the client SDK are you using?

Comment: 11.2.0 (targeting API 26)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the Firebase team and they said this is a known issue that will be fixed in a future release.

Comment: is it still Known issue? or any workaround is there.